# webpack-node-externals - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-4

This is the **Webpack config:**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    entry: './server/index.js',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'server.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __isBrowser__: "false"
        })
    ]
};
```

I've configured the webpack command like this:

```
NODE_ENV=production node --max-old-space-size=2048 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.server.js --mode=production
```

The command --`max-old-space-size` is configured with 2 GB of RAM but it isn't enough, I still have the error...

[image]

My computer has 4 GB of RAM.

**Packages:**

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve it, I had MongoDB, MySQL, Docker, Chrome, and other things running and for that reason my RAM didn't work well in that moment xD.